# RethinkDB on the BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack, rethinkdb

I am trying to get the RetinkDB database solution running on the BeagleBone Black.

I have followed the [instructions](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/raspbian/) for the Pi but have run into a compiler error.

The line from *make*:

```
[110/398] CC build/release_system/obj/rdb_protocol/terms/json.o
```

ends up with the following: (after a mess of compiler output)

```
src/rdb_protocol/terms/json.cc:46:44:   instantiated from here
./src/rapidjson/reader.h:697:17: error: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [build/release_system/obj/rdb_protocol/terms/json.o] Error 1
make: *** [make] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what to try next... The build takes quite awhile so I'm setting up a build environment on my slackware box.

Thanks in advance

update: (8/22/15)
I did

```
export CXXFLAGS="-Wno-error=type-limits"
```

This time *make* lasted through step 386...

```
   [387/394] LD build/release_system/rethinkdb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [build/release_system/rethinkdb] Error 1
make: *** [make] Error 2
root@beaglebone:~/beagle_setup/rethinkdb-2.1.1#
```

There are still many type warnings "[-Wtype-limits]" but it seems as though the compiler at least continued... I feel like I'm just wasting time and there is something fundamental I haven't done.

update: (8/26/15)
I updated to Jessie and followed the generic [Debian Instructions](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/debian/) and the build was successful out of the box! I then proceeded to take a fresh factory image and try it strait away. That way I eliminated any library weirdness that I might have caused in my hacking. Same deal different file...

```
[-Werror=type-limits]
```

I'm not sure what's going on... This is out of my league.
I'm now doing a freshly flashed Debian 8 image with all the dependencies I need to see if the build succeeds. If so I'll have to leave this be...

Thanks

Update [9/9/15]
I tried to build the latest 2.1.3 rethinkdb server on a Debian 7.8 image of the beaglebone and it failed at linking. It seems like no matter what I do I can't build the server on Wheezy...

Update: 9/14/15
Version 2.0.1 builds without the need for ALLOW_WARNINGS on the beaglebone. I suspect that all 2.0.x versionds will build and run correctly.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Try adding `ALLOW_WARNINGS=1` the the `make` command line. It will turn off `-Werror`.

Comment: Hey @physineer, you might want to try pulling some things from this small script I wrote for the Raspberry Pi - https://gist.github.com/dalanmiller/2365fb938fe61f4761c1

But the `ALLOW_WARNINGS=1` that @AtnNn mentioned above should definitely get the job done.

Comment: @dalanmiller, thanks for the link I may need to go that route. As the update to Jessie brings with it the 4.1.x kernel. Not so great as the cape support is apparently lacking... I had to bounce back to the 3.8.x-bone7x kernel to recover my serial ports. -> My next task (assuming the build works) is to package the build for distribution and post it to my [GitHub](https://github.com/10man).

Comment: @AtnNn&dalanmiller  I forgot to say thanks for the comments :-[  So thank you for the help and God Bless!!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `ALLOW_WARNINGS=1` should get you past this issue on the Beaglebone. Let me know if you have more issues!